# How to change dependency registration at run time using simple injector?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm using the [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com) IoC framework, and I would like to be able to change the dependency registration at run time. For example, I have two implementations, `A` and `B`, of interface `I`.  Implementation `A` is registered at app start, but depending on some flag which can change during runtime, I would like to switch the implementation.  We are currently doing this the `OnActionExecuting` event of our `BaseController`, which all of our controllers inherit from. Here is the sample code of what I am trying to do.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(
    ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (IsRuntimeFlag)
    {
        // check current implementation type and 
        // change implementation to A
    }
    else
    {
        // check current implementation type and 
        // change implementation to B
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you need to do that manually? What about use a IOC Container framework?

Comment: I'd recommend combining a Factory with a Strategy pattern, rather than using a DI Container for this. Use the Container to resolve your object graph early on. See [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case `IsRuntimeFlag` is a configuration value (thus cannot change during the lifetime of the application), you can make the registration as follows:

```cs
if (IsRuntimeFlag)
{
    container.Register<I, A>();
}
else
{
    container.Register<I, B>();
}
```

or equally:

```
container.Register(typeof(I), IsRuntimeFlag ? typeof(A) : typeof(B));
```

In case the value can change during the lifetime of the application a proxy or [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) that deals with dispatching to the right instance is the right solution:

```cs
public sealed class RuntimeFlagIComposite : I
{
    private readonly A a;
    private readonly B b;

    public RuntimeFlagIComposite(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    void I.Method() => this.Instance.Method();

    private I Instance => IsRuntimeFlag ? this.a : this.b;
}
```

Because the composite directly depends on `A` and `B`, you can simply register it as follows:

```cs
container.Register<I, RuntimeFlagIComposite>();

// Register A and B with their required lifestyles
container.Register<A>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Register<B>(Lifestyle.Transient);
```

You can also let your composite depend on the `I` abstraction itself instead of the concrete `A` and `B` implementations:

```cs
public class RuntimeFlagIComposite : I
{
    private I a;
    private I b;

    public RuntimeFlagIComposite(I a, I b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Depending on the `I` abstraction makes this class more flexible and more testable. It does mean however, that you need to register it a little bit different. This can be done using `RegisterConditional`. Here's an example:

```cs
container.Register<I, RuntimeFlagIComposite>();

container.RegisterConditional<I, A>(c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "a");
container.RegisterConditional<I, B>(c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "b");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, this flag is unknown at the time of container registration, and can change throughout the lifetime of the application.   I guess I can set a global flag and change it later on during the application, but I don't think that it is a clean approach to this.  Upon a closer look, I do think the composite pattern might work in this case.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi Steven,
Just wondering if you have any other ideas.  Upon trying to implement this, i realized that the flag also depends things in the web app layer, cookies values specifically, as opposed to the service layer, which is where the composite would be.  Therefore, the composite would not have access to the flag.  Thanks again in advance.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. If the composite would depend on UI specific things, it should be defined in the UI layer. Since the interface is defined in a lower layer, it is absolutely fine to define it in your UI layer (or you could even make it part of your composition root).