# How to change CacheClients at runtime in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I'd like (through app/web configuration perhaps) to change the cache client used in my ServiceStack application, during runtime.

For example, I have this currently:

```
 container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

I'd like at runtime to change this to a Redis ICacheClient usage. What if I had two containers registered (one Memory and on Redis). Is it possible to switch between containers at runtime in a call like this in my service:

```
    public object Get(FooRequest request)
    {
        string cacheKey = UrnId.CreateWithParts("Foo", "Bar");
        return RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache, cacheKey, sCacheDuration, () =>
            {
                return TestRepository.Foos;
            });
    }
```

EDIT:

Note, after more research, if you have more than one ICacheClient registered:

```
        container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
        container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

Then accessing base.Cache within your service will return the most recent ICacheClient that was registered... ie: in the case above, MemoryCacheClient.

So with the ability to access the Cache object from within the service, I'd just need a way to get a particular Cache from my registered caches, which I can't see any property for.

Answer (score 1):

Doing something like this would allow you to register different providers with the container based on a web config setting:

```
var redisCacheString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseRedis"];
var useRedis = false;
if (!bool.TryParse(redisCacheString, out useRedis))
{
  container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
  container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
}
else
{
  container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's good for registering caches, but I'm looking to register all the caches I could possibly need, then swap them out at runtime, while the service is already running.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you'll need more flexibility rather than just a simple registration on the composite root, you can try to implement the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) in your container registration.

steven [explains this pattern using simple injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083919/how-to-change-dependency-registration-at-run-time-using-simple-injector) but I think it can be implemented with the IOC provided OOB by SS or any other

I hope that helps